# Create a dataframe i nR

Tags: r, dataframe, random, simulation

I would like to create a dataframe with 117 columns and 90 rows, the first ones being: `ID`, `date1`, `date2`, `Category`, `DR1`, `DRM01`, `DRM02`, `DRM03` .... up to `DRM111`. For the first column, it would have values ranging from 1 to 3. In `date1` it would have a fixed value, which would be `"2022-01-05"`, in `date2`, it would have values between `2021-12-20` to the maximum that it gives. `Category` can be ABC or ERF, in `DR1` would be values that would vary from 200 to 250, and finally, in `DRM` columns, would be values that would vary from 0 to 300. Is it possible to create a dataframe like this?

Comment: Hi Antonio. What is the goal here? Are asking how to create random data (subject to specific constraints)? Are you trying to read in/parse data from another source? `data.frame(ID = 1:3)` creates a data frame with an "ID" column that takes the values 1, 2, 3. Does that help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wondering if this is an effort at simulation. The first few tasks seem blindly obvious but the last call to replicate with simplify=FALSE might have been a bit less than trivial.

```
test <- data.frame( ID = rep(1:3, length=90),
          date1 =  as.Date( "2022-01-05"),
          date2= seq( as.Date("2021-12-20"), length.out=90, by=1),
          #Category  = ???? so far not specified
          DR1 = sample( 200:250, 90, repl=TRUE),  #need repl is length need is long
          setNames( replicate(111, { sample(0:300, 90)}, simplify=FALSE) ,
                     nm=paste("DRM",1:111) ) )
```

Snipped the last 105 rows of the output from str:

```
str(test)
'data.frame':   90 obs. of  115 variables:
 $ ID     : int  1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3 1 ...
 $ date1  : Date, format: "2022-01-05" "2022-01-05" "2022-01-05" "2022-01-05" ...
 $ data2  : Date, format: "2021-12-20" "2021-12-21" "2021-12-22" "2021-12-23" ...
 $ DR1    : int  229 218 240 243 221 202 242 221 237 208 ...
 $ DRM.1  : int  41 238 142 100 19 56 224 152 85 84 ...
 $ DRM.2  : int  150 185 141 55 34 83 88 105 165 294 ...
 $ DRM.3  : int  144 22 237 174 78 291 120 63 261 236 ...
 $ DRM.4  : int  223 105 263 214 45 226 129 80 182 15 ...
 $ DRM.5  : int  27 108 288 237 129 251 150 70 300 243 ...
 # additional rows elided
```

The last item in that construction returns a list that has 111 "columns" with ascending numbered names. I admit to being puzzled about why there were periods in the DRM names but then realized that the `data.frame` function uses `check.names` to make sure they are legitimate, so the spaces from paste were converted to periods. If you don't like periods then use `paste0`.

Comment: I adjusted in the question about `Category` column.  Can't it be `DRM01` instead of `DRM.1`?

Comment: You should be able to figure out how to do Category from the other code I offered. I don't know how to neatly do 01 if you are going up to 111. If you can settle for 001 then using `sprinf`  is the way to go. (No coding without a checkmark.)

Comment: @IRTFM one leading zero you can use `formatC`. `paste0("DRM", formatC(1:111, width = 2, format = "d", flag = "0"))`

Comment: Question fully answered now. Added the tags I thought might be useful for searchers of the future.